# How to change the DB location using c# Litedb (noSQL)?

Tags: c#, database, nosql, litedb

I'm new to noSQL and trying to use [litedb](https://www.litedb.org/).

I want to change the location of the db storage.

Right now this code:

```
using (var db = new LiteDatabase(@"MyData.db"))
{
}
```

Creates the database at ***projectName\bin\Debug***

Is there a way to create the DB from the root of the project?

Is there a reason to leave the DB there? Maybe I'm wrong trying to do this.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In connection-string](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/wiki/Connection-String) you are using relative path, it will be created where the application is located, you can use the full path to specify the location. 
Eg: `new LiteDatabase("C:\Folder\MyData.db")`

And to change the location you simply need to use [File.Move()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=netframework-4.8) on your existing database to move it to the desired location, then open the database with that new path.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like placing the db outside of the debug location is a good idea.